# How can I find the X nature from this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

In one question from my university exam, it was given this circuit:

[image]

**The component X can be a capacitor, inductor or a resistor.**

where all components values are unknown, less R2, it's equal 1kΩ. 
The question has given  me this transfer function of output current io(it is been illustrated in the figure above):

[image]

The first thing I thought was analyse the transfer function at two extremes, low frequency and high frequency, so I found these expressions:

[image]

[image]

My objective was analyse, if the  X current(ix(t)) increases or decreases in these two extremes and then I'd have an idea about impedance and finally know the X nature. But I found a problem, I don't have any idea about the output frequency, consequently I don't know the output phase, if the output current increases or decreases and then I don't know how to find out the X nature. Could someone give me an idea how to solve this problem??

Comment: The output frequency equals the input frequency and I'm sure the exam question would have said that the circuit was "linear" - did you miss that bit?

Comment: So sorry, I forget one information. Yes the circuit is linear. I updated the question, exists 3 possibilities for X.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your question, so I will state my assumptions clearly:

- \$R2 = 1k\Omega\$, all other values are unknown
- The X component is either a capacitor or an inductor. If it is a inductor, it has impedance \$Z(s) = sL\$. If it is a capacitor, it has impedance \$Z(s) = 1/(sC)\$
- No funny business: there are no negative resistances, capacitances or inductances in the circuit

Now you can simply use algebra and Kirchoff's laws. Before doing the math it is hard to know if there is one, many or no solution.

This is the brute force approach, and it will work. You should give it a try. However, a experienced engineer may notice a few things that might make solving the equations a lot easier:

- You can easily run a "sanity-check" in this circuit with \$ \omega = 0\$ and \$ \omega = \infty \$
- Notice this looks like a Wheatstone bridge circuit. As such, you should pay attention to the **ratio** between impedances of R2 and R3, and between R1 and X. This tells you something about the number of solutions this problem can have.